# Thread value not cached by threads even without volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

```
class Counter
{
    public int i=0;
    public void increment()
    {
        i++;
        System.out.println("i is "+i);
        System.out.println("i/=2 executing");
        i=i+22;
        System.out.println("i is (after i+22) "+i);
        System.out.println("i+=1 executing");
        i++;
        System.out.println("i is (after i++) "+i);
    }
    public void decrement()
    {
        i--;
        System.out.println("i is "+i);
        System.out.println("i*=2 executing");
        i=i*2;
        System.out.println("i is after i*2"+i);
        System.out.println("i-=1 executing");
        i=i-1;
        System.out.println("i is after i-1 "+i);
    }
    public int value()
    {
        return i;
    } }

class ThreadA
{
    public ThreadA(final Counter c)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Thread A trying to increment");
                c.increment();
                System.out.println("Increment completed "+c.i);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
class ThreadB
{
    public ThreadB(final Counter c)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Thread B trying to decrement");
                c.decrement();
                System.out.println("Decrement completed "+c.i);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
class ThreadInterference
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Counter c=new Counter();
        new ThreadA(c);
        new ThreadB(c); 
    }
}
```

In the above code, ThreadA first got access to Counter object and incremented the value along with performing some extra operations. For the very first time ThreadA does not have a cached value of i. But after the execution of i++ (in first line) it will get cache the value. Later on the value is updated and gets 24. According to the program, as the variable i is not volatile so the changes will be done in the local cache of ThreadA,

Now when ThreadB accesses the decrement() method the value of i is as updated by ThreadA i.e. 24. How could that be possible?

Comment: On Intel-32 etc, cache coherency is implemented in hardware, though compiler re-ordering can still cause 'problems'. The remaining issue of values being cached in CPU registers is only likely to be an issue with trivial test cases.  Calling almost anything, especially a massive thing like 'println', will surely cause all the likely registers to be pushed onto the stack and so into L1 cache at least.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that threads won't see each updates that other threads make to shared data is as inappropriate as assuming that all threads *will* see each other's updates immediately.

The important thing is to take account of the *possibility* of not seeing updates - not to rely on it.

There's another issue besides not seeing the update from other threads, mind you - all of your operations act in a "read, modify, write" sense... if another thread modifies the value after you've read it, you'll basically ignore it.

So for example, suppose `i` is 5 when we reach this line:

```
i = i * 2;
```

... but half way through it, another thread modifies it to be 4.

That line can be thought of as:

```
int tmp = i;
tmp = tmp * 2;
i = tmp;
```

If the second thread changes `i` to 4 after the first line in the "expanded" version, then even if `i` is volatile the write of 4 will still be effectively lost - because by that point, `tmp` is 5, it will be doubled to 10, and then 10 will be written out.

Comment: So do you mean that, if the data is shared data, then one thread can see other thread's updates. So caching will not take place in case of shared data?

Comment: @GowthamGutha: It's not that it *won't* - it's that it *might* not. The Java memory model specifies where updates *must* be seen... but it allows implementations to vary in terms of *exactly* when updates are seen, within those rules.

Comment: According to Java Memory Model, when does a thread cache a value and where updates are seen?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [`JLS 8.3.1.4`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4):

> The Java programming language allows threads to access shared
>   variables (§17.1). As a rule, to ensure that shared variables are
>   consistently and reliably updated, a thread should ensure that it has
>   exclusive use of such variables by obtaining a lock that,
>   conventionally, enforces mutual exclusion for those shared variables........*A field may be 
>   declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that
>   all threads see a consistent value for the variable*

Although not always but there is still a chance that the shared values among threads are not consistenly and reliably updated, which would lead to some unpredictable outcome of program. In code given below

```
class Test {
    static int i = 0, j = 0;
    static void one() { i++; j++; }
    static void two() {
        System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
    }
}
```

If, one thread repeatedly calls the method one (but no more than Integer.MAX_VALUE times in all), and another thread repeatedly calls the method two then method two could occasionally print a value for j that is greater than the value of i, because the example includes no synchronization and, the shared values of i and j might be updated out of order. 
But if you declare `i` and `j` to be `volatile` , This allows method one and method two to be executed concurrently, but guarantees that accesses to the shared values for `i` and `j` occur exactly as many times, and in exactly the same order, as they appear to occur during execution of the program text by each thread. Therefore, **the shared value for `j` is never greater than that for `i`,because each update to i must be reflected in the shared value for i before the update to j occurs**.

Answer (score 0):

Now i came to know that common objects (the objects that are being shared by multiple threads) are not cached by those threads. As the object is common, Java Memory Model is smart enough to identify that common objects when cached by threads could produce surprising results.

Answer (score 0):

> How could that be possible?

Because there is nowhere in the JLS that says values have to be cached within a thread.

This is what the spec does say:

If you have a non-volatile variable `x`, and it's updated by a thread `T1`, there is no guarantee that `T2` can ever observe the change of `x` by `T1`. The only way to guarantee that `T2` sees a change of `T1` is with a `happens-before` relationship.

It just so happens that some implementations of Java cache non-volatile variables within a thread in certain cases. In other words, you can't rely on a non-volatile variable being cached.